# given a set of points and vectors, expand the set

Tags: metric-spaces, vectors, regression

I have a set of $n$ points: $(Sx, Sy, Sz)$ and $n$ vectors: $(Vx,Vy,Vz)$, each uniquely mapped to one another. The set also exists inside of an $X*Y*Z$ size rectangular space. I want to ensure a consistent density of points in my space, which might include generating new points and calculating vectors for them.

What's the best way to accomplish both of these problems? (ensuring density and generating vectors)